# How to copy paste merged cells in excel using interop

Tags: c#

I have a excel sheet in which C,D,E columns are merged in to one column, F&G,H&I,J&K,M&N columns are merged. I have to create rows dynamically based on the no of items presented in the list(lstmasterHeader). I am doing copy paste from existing row to create new row but it is creating row but missing merged cells, please let me know if any other way available to fulfill my requirement.

Please refer attached image for more information about columns structure. Below code missing merged cells while creating a row.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lstmasterHeader.Count; i++)
    { var source = ws.Range["A38:O38"].Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
       Excel.Range dest = ws.Range["A39:O39"];
       ws.Range["A38:O38"].Copy(dest); 
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Excel sheet with merged cells]

Comment: The Excel Interop API is the same as the API used by VBA macros. You can record a macro doing what you want, inspect the code and perform the same steps in C#. If you want to insert a new empty row to a table you can use the `Insert Row` command instead of copy/pasting the last table row

Comment: Hi Panagiotis,I tried to insert but merged cells not inserting as expected.

Comment: if list have 10 records I need to create 10 rows and insert data in to newly created rows. i variable is used to increment row value while updating  data. For instance ws.Cells[rowcount + i, 3] = lstmasterHeader[i].ProjectId;

Comment: Hi Kanavos, Please provide sample code if any to insert new by creating merged  rows as shown in the image.

Comment: header color applying for newly inserted rows as well, could you any one help me to get rid of  back ground color red as shown in the image attached

Comment: thanks for your advise and working now as expected.